# What are differents to install Sqlite for ASP.net between adding SQLite component from NUGet and copying System.Data.SQLite.dll to \Bin folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I plan to use SQLite  for ASP.net web application in VS 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019), and deploy the web application to remote hosting.

I google some resources, I find there are two way to install SQLite for ASP.net web application.

The one is to install it by adding  SQLite component from NUGet in  VS 2019, you can see Image 1

The two is to copy `System.Data.SQLite.dll` to `\Bin` folde of a project.

**Q1:**

Where can I download the alone latest `System.Data.SQLite.dll` ?

**Q2:**

What are differents to  install Sqlite for ASP.net between  the one way and   the two way?

**Image 1**
[image]

Comment: Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318899/add-reference-to-dll-vs-adding-a-nuget-package-in-net-standard-project. In technical terms there is no real difference between the two. However manually adding a reference has some potential risks which can be easily avoided. The latest version can be found on either the nuget side or the official docs https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: NuGet was introduced a long time ago to change how people acquire dependencies, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget So, it is time for you to re-study the whole ecosystem, after years of left behind. There isn't a need to open a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow, as people discussed the same topics years ago. There are also good books and tutorials if you use search engines.